# How are AutomationPeers used in a .NET Maui Windows app?

Tags: accessibility, maui

Are there any resources showing how to use AutomationPeers in an .NET Maui Windows app? Traditional Xamarin apps would use Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers, but I can't find mention of peers up at resources such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers` instead of `Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers` .

> This namespace requires the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` NuGet package

Check if the package has been installed in your project .

Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.automation.peers?view=winui-3.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32